# How to make the prompt beep with every key press/character printed?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, prompt

You know how hollywood movies depict hacking scenes with fast yet scrolling CLI technobabble in this fashion : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-jkj60TUWaE

I want to know how to modify linux to make the computer beep as soon as a key is pressed (like an old 386 machine that beeps when pressing too many keys at once or pressing backspace in an empty prompt), and maybe to make it even more hollywood-ish, on every character displayed, combined with something to slow the display a little.

Answer (score 1):

You may do this with [`xset`](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man1/xset.1.html) (with the caveat that most of the things that `xset` asks for may be ignored):

> The **`c`** option controls key click. This option can take an optional value, a preceding dash(**`-`**), or an '**`on/off`**' flag. If no parameter or the '**`on`**' flag is given, the system defaults will be used. If the dash or '**`off`**' flag is used, keyclick will be disabled. If a value from 0 to 100 is given, it is used to indicate volume, as a percentage of the maximum. The X server will set the volume to the nearest value that the hardware can support.